# Jmeter to determine the time taken to send 1000 requests

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am using Jmeter normal Thread Group to simulate 1 user to loop and send a total of 1000 requests. Is the total time taken to send 1000 requests the total runtime?

Eg. 1 user, 1000 requests (looped to do so), on top right after it finishes I see a timing of 1 min 40 seconds. 1 user spends 100 seconds to send 1000 requests?
So average of 1 requests per 0.1 second see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's a viable approach. However if you want the total time to execute 1000 requests in the loop to appear in the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) and/or [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) you could amend your test plan a little bit like:

- [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) with 1 user and 1 loop and 0 ramp-up

  - [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-transaction-controller)

    - [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) with 1000 loops

      - Your [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)

This way the Transaction Controller will generate a synthetic Sample Result and its elapsed time will be the sum of all its children (1000 Sampler executions)

[image]